# Compare Multidimensional Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, multidimensional-array

I have a huge hash (JSON) that I want to compare to a "master key" by deleting the values that are dissimilar then totaling a value set.

I thought it would be a good way to handle test scoring with complex scoring criterion.

Advice about how to do this? Any gems exist to make my life easier?

```
{
  "A" => 10,
  "B" => 7,
  etc
    ....
```

The hash is constructed like `test[answer] => test[point_value]` and the question key/value is the answer/point value.

So if I want to compare to a master_key and remove *dissimilar* items (not remove similar ones like `arr1-arr2` does...then total the values, what would be best?

Comment: From your example, the first question is "A" and the answer is "10"? or is the answer "A" and if you get that answer you get 10 points, and if the answer is anything other than "A", you get no points?

Comment: Answer is "A", if that's correct, you get 10, if it's not "A", you get 0.
I'm thinking I should just reduce it to a 1D array...how would I flatten and reduce this to get "A" : "10"...?

Comment: the Array object has a `flatten` method. It only flattens the first level, you have to specify a number if you want it to recurse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting the hashes to ruby hashes i'd do something like this

```
 tester = { :"first" =>  { :"0" => { :"0" => { :"B" => 10 }, :"1" => { :"B" => 7 }, :"2" => { :"B" => 5 } } }}
 master = { :"first" => { :"0" => { :"0" => { :"A" => 10 }, :"1" => { :"B" => 7 }, :"2" => { :"B" => 5 } } }}
tester.reduce(0) do |score, (test,  section)| 
  section.each do |group, questions|
    questions.each do |question, answer|
      if answer.keys.first == master[test][group][question].keys.first
        score += answer.values.first
      end
    end
  end
  score
end
```

Comment: I've flattened this to just: `[{"A"=>10},{"B" => 7}...]` :) Can you update? I'll update my question in a sec...I wasn't thinking when I posted. No reason for all that stuff--that's all coming from the json side of me. :)

Comment: your update is a hash and your comment is an array of hashes, which one is it? Both shouldn't be too difficult to compare to a master copy, i'll  update when you get back to me

Comment: Just a hash, not multidimensional anymore, though you can just update...don't have to delete a good answer totally. I'll probably refer back to this in the future.

Comment: I think you'd still need to to specify some way which answer corresponds to what question. Hashes are unordered(technically they maintain order in ruby but it's bad practice to make this assumption imo), so you can't rely on the fact that the first key to a master represents the same answer as the first key to a test hash

Comment: I see. So maybe I need to hash `{0 => {"A" => 10}, 1 => {"B" => 7}}`? When I build the hash, I'll index per answer? Wasn't aware that it was a ruby thing to keep hash order.

Comment: Any way to ignore nil and blank values?

Comment: You can use #reject method. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject and just check for a value of nil

Comment: But I want to keep the key/value it in the hash, I just don't want to sum it.